# Windows server connect to different server Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Windows servers, one of them has Mysql installed on. I want connect to the Mysql server from a different server, but i'm getting this error:

> in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\config.php on line 11
>   Warning:  mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]:  (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party  did not properly respond after a period of time, or established  connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\config.php on line 11

Comment: have u given mysql permissions to your user to connect remote server.

Comment: yes it has the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Firewall is turned off.